# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

Every time I try to enable the command line tool in phpstorm I get this error which I couldn't handle :

> Problem. Failed to determine version. 
>  Output Warning:
>   require(C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\MyApp\vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs/functions.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\MyApp\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on
>   line 54

Comment: That error is saying that it cant find `autoload_real.php`

Comment: @P0lT10n Wrong, the error is saying that it can't find the `functions.php` file, and its being called on the line 54 of the `autoload_real.php` file

Comment: @leo_ap yes, you are right, i miss read it, i dont know why did i said that

Answer (score 2):

By running `composer install` I have fixed a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the path `C:\Program Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\MyApp\vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs/functions.php` and that the file has the correct permissions.

Comment: the error says that it cant find the functions.php in autoloadreal.php so i tried to change the line 54 in autoload, this is the line 54 :

Comment: function composerRequire11ec8737d802fa7d48e506d9ede21a56($file)
{
require($file);  //line54
}

Comment: instead of require($file) i put the relative path of the file functions.php, but i didnt work

Comment: i made the file functions.php's permission read only, but i got this error when i retried to enable the command line tool in phpstorm: Failed to load commands: Failed to execute 'php.exe C:\Program Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\MyApp\app\console -V'.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled phpstorm, then I got an other error that said I had to change the date.timezone, so I changed it in the file php.ini.